# How to print out text (SDL_TTF) from an array?

Tags: c, sdl-ttf

I posted parts of my code that I think are relevent. I'm trying to draw out some text via SDL_TTF for my menu. I'm getting a string of char from the server everytime i clicked on a button. Something like "I1P1I2P1I3P1I4P1I5P1I6P1I7P1I8P1I9P1" "I1" means lobby 1 and P1 means 1 player is connected. However i only want to print out "I1" and then have bunch of space say 200 pixels and then print out "P1" then jump to next line to print "I2" and "P1". I tried the text warpping but it's ignoreing it and printing out the whole line of text. Secondly how can i go about to print empty spaces between "I1" and "P1". Is there an easier/efficient way to go about printing text via SDL_TTF from an array?

```
typedef struct
{
    Menu menu;

    SDL_Texture     *label;
    SDL_Renderer    *rendererMenu;
    TTF_Font        *font;
    char            *lobbyResponse;
}   MenuState;

void dispayText(char *text, MenuState *menu)
{
    SDL_Color color         = {255, 255, 255, 255};
    SDL_Surface *surface    = TTF_RenderText_Blended_Wrapped(menu->font, text, color, 4);
    menu->label             = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(menu->rendererMenu, surface);
    menu->menu.labelW       = surface->w;
    menu->menu.labelH       = surface->h;
    //pos.x = x;
    //pos.y = y;
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}



int processEventsMenu(SDL_Window *window, MenuState *menu, TCPsocket *tcpsock)
{
    SDL_Event ev;
    menu->lobbyResponse = malloc(sizeof(char[1024])); // <- moved it here for clarity

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
    {
        switch(ev.type)
        {
            case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if (ev.button.button == SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
                {
                    SendLobbyMessage(tcpsock, refreshCommand);
                    ReceiveLobbyMessage(tcpsock, menu->lobbyResponse);
                    printf("Created lobby with id: %c\n",menu->lobbyResponse[0]);
                    dispayText(menu->lobbyResponse, menu);
                    printf("Lobbys: %c\n", menu->lobbyResponse[0]);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code that is not inside a function will not be considered by the machine while executing the program. You have one line of code between functions `displayText` and `processEventsMenu`.

Comment: nounoursnoir I actually just stripped out a lot of my code. The code you are refering to exits in another function. I just wanted to include it so that you can see that i initilized it properly.

Comment: mm ok but I think you should write this line of code apart from the block of code you wrote, and explain that this is an important detail to notice, from another function in your program. To me this looks like a senseless line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
puts("Something \t\t Something\n"); // \t allows to put "empty spaces"
```

I advise writing a function which would format the string as you'd like before printing it. Consider using `strtok_r()`. Another solution is to iterate char by char into the string and print `\n` to "jump to the next line" everytime you encounter `|`.

One possible solution which seems to work for me is :

```
const char*         s = "I1P1I2P1I3P1I4P1I5P1I6P1I7P1I8P1I9P1";
const unsigned   size = strlen(s);
char*          result = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s) + 2 * strlen(s) / 4) + 1);
/* We allocated the memory necessary to put the whole of the string `s`
inside of the string `result`, and a tab and a newline, considering
that for every 4 characters inside of `s`, we will put 1 tab and 1
newline*/

int                 i = 0;
int                 j = 0;

while (i < size + 1)
{
    result[j] = s[i];
    if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)       // Every 2 char that were passed from _s_ to _result_
    {
        if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0)
            result[++j] = '\n'; // Either we add a newline...
        else
            result[++j] = '\t'; // ... or we add a tab
    }
    j++;
    i++;
}
printf("Original String : %s\n", s);
printf("Formatted String : \n%s\n", result);
```

Output is :

```
Original String : I1P1I2P1I3P1I4P1I5P1I6P1I7P1I8P1I9P1
Formatted String : 
I1  P1
I2  P1
I3  P1
I4  P1
I5  P1
I6  P1
I7  P1
I8  P1
I9  P1
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. Just to clarify, my menu is a graphical interface which is drawn with SDL. I have 2 colums, one that is Lobby ID on the left and one #Players on the right. I want to somehow draw the data into my menu - in which i accomplished to some degree. Right now my function will print the entire string onto my screen/menu. I want to be able to add space even though the array has no space and text-wrap automatically..

Comment: What if you wrote a function that would format correctly your string before printing it ? I could help you with that

Comment: Hi Badda I get what you are saying, i've also thought about it. Do you have any example on how to implement it?

Comment: @xxFlashxx I edited my answer with an example. May be this could work for you ? Also it is possible to add plurals tabs if you want more space between `I1`and `P1`

Comment: I permitted myself to modify your code a bit and tried to make it easier to read, feel free to refuse it if you think it's not better or easier to understand

Comment: I think your edit was clearly an improvement. I did accept it, except the declaration of `i`and `j`which I thought is more logical to do just before the beginning of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could put spaces and newlines after each n character, since you have a regular pattern of characters. What you want is to have a space (or tab or whatever) after the first 2 characters, then a newline after the next 2 characters, then a space after the next 2 characters and a newline after the next  2 characters, etc.

To me, the easiest way to do so is a simple `while` loop that prints the characters one by one, adding spaces and newlines whenever some spaces or newlines should be printed.

You can iterate through the string you want to format:

```
int     main(void)
{
    int      i = 0;
    int      j = 0;
    char*    s = "I1P1I2P1I3P1I4P1I5P1I6P1I7P1I8P1I9P1";

    while (s[j]) // while we have not reached the end of the string s
    {
        if ((i + 1) % 6 == 0)
            printf("\n");           // print a newline
        else if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            printf("  ");           // print some spaces (or whatever you want)
        else
            printf("%c", s[j++]);   // print a character then increment the index of s
        i++;
    }
}
```

You can also increment through the line that the program is writing:

```
int main(void)
{
    int     j = 0;
    int     k = 0;        // k is the index of the line we're currently writing
    char*   s = "I1P1I2P1I3P1I4P1I5P1I6P1I7P1I8P1I9P1";
    while (s[j])
    {
        if (k == 5)       // If the program has already written 4 chars from s in the line...
        {
            printf("\n"); // ...go to a new line.
            k = 0;
        }
        else if (k == 2)  // If the program has already written 2 chars from s in the line...
        {
            printf(" ");  // ...add some spaces.
            k++;
        }
        else              // Else, print a char from s in the current line
        {
            printf("%c", s[j++]);
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
I1  P1
I2  P1
I3  P1
I4  P1
I5  P1
I6  P1
I7  P1
I8  P1
I9  P1
```

Comment: `if ((i + 1) % 6) == 0` you forgot a bracket I think

Comment: I missplaced it actually ty